# Page Break not working for rectangle in page footer SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2012

I am unable to get page breaking property of Rectangle(which is inside page footer)working/showing up.
I am trying to add it into a simple report, which as page header ,body and page footer.
Is it a bug or am I missing something?

I've tried setting the rectangle property. But not successful.

[image]

Comment: Can you show some examples? Maybe what you've tried already, along with your expected output?

Comment: Not sure if I understand this correctly. Wouldn't a rectangle in a footer not be able use use a page break as footer will print all it's content on each page.

Comment: @BishNaboB I've attached picture to my post.

Comment: @Snowlokk That was exact thing I was thinking too. But I can't get the page break effect. I don't know why. Actually That "RESERVATION" textbox should be in next page.